# Is there a Python analogue for JavaScript's module.exports?

Tags: python, module

In JavaScript, a module's default object can be set using "module.exports":

```
MyCache = require("./MyCache");
cache = new MyCache();
```

Similar behavior can be achieved in Python with:

```
from MyCache import Create as MyCache
cache = MyCache()
```

...but is it possible to set a default object in Python?

```
import MyCache
cache = MyCache()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.  When you import a module, you import a module.  You can't make a module masquerade as something else.  If you want to import a class, you can already do that very simply using `from module import SomeClass` as in your example.